# get seen count of Telegram messages in php

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I want to get the message's seen count via Telegram bot api, telegram cli or other ways.

I have all message ids and the Telegram bot is admin in my channel.

Please guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you can not get this type of data by bot at this time. :(